# Google Analytics Goal Pages Triggering Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I run analytics for a college and I've set-up conversion goals to trigger when a user visits:

(Beings with)

```
/application-thanks-CO
```

After going through the previous funnel:

```
/application-form
```

The application thanks have custom parameters which link up to individual applications (this lets me track an individual down from each application submitted), so the actual goal url might look like

```
/application-thanks-CO?sid=11359
```

However, my problem is that sometimes Analytics is triggering multiple goal completions per thank-you page, i.e.:

```
/application-thanks-CO?sid=11359 Goal completions: 3
```

This might be happening from a user going back and forth from the same page, a social media widget, or even refreshing. However, what I do know is that since each thank-you page with custom parameters (as above) can only be based on one application, more than one goal completion is simply incorrect.

How can I stop this from happening? Is there anywhere in Google Analytics I can set-up so goal locations so that they can only be 'Triggered' once?

Comment: Actually this won't happen from going back and fort or refreshing since goals are triggered only once per session (see e.g. here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2679221?hl=en). This happens only when the user has started a new session in between (e.g. saved the page somewhere, shared the link etc).

Comment: Interesting! Thanks Eike! Would you know any resolution?

Do you think it's because I had a previous funnel set-up?